# Cecil Custom Attribute value is empty

Tags: c#, .net-core, mono.cecil

I have a basic DTO. It has a `Required` attribute on it with an `ErrorMessage`. I'm using `Cecil` to try and get the value of the `ErrorMessage` property but the value for it is empty.

i.e

```
public class FooDto
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cannot be empty")]
   public string Bar { get; set;}
}
```

This is how I get the attribute:

```
var myLib = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(@"C:\lib.dll");
var type = myLib.MainModule.GetType("Namespace.FooDto");
foreach (var prop in type.Properties)
{
    foreach (var customattr in prop.CustomAttributes)
    {
        foreach (var customProp in customattr.Properties)
        {
            if (customProp.Name == "ErrorMessage")
               Console.WriteLine(customProp.Argument.Value.ToString()); // this is always empty string
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: If I use classic reflection, I can get the value of `ErrorMessage` but I want to use Cecil because I'm already doing other things with the library in my code and don't want a hybrid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how below code is different from your approach but I can get "Cannot be empty" output in console

```
var attrs = type.Properties
    .SelectMany(p => p.CustomAttributes)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Properties)
    .Where(x => x.Name == "ErrorMessage")
    .Select(x => x.Argument.Value)
    .ToArray();

foreach (var attribute in attrs)
    Console.WriteLine(attribute);
```

I tested it with .net 4.5.2 and mono 0.10.3

Comment: Im running .net core 2.2, so maybe that could be the difference?

Comment: @JohanP quite possible. At the moment I can't test it with .net core, sorry. I will respond as soon as try code above with .net core